# Teradata stored procedure with dynamic parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I'm trying to create a dunamic procedure that, given a specific dbname and tablename, creates a set of select statements using all column names available for that table.

I'm using the following code:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE sum_col 
( 
IN TABLENAME VARCHAR(50), DBNAME VARCHAR(286)
)

BEGIN

DECLARE SqlTxt VARCHAR(3000);

FOR cur AS

      SELECT

         TRIM(a.DatabaseName) AS DBNAME,
         TRIM(a.TABLENAME) AS TABLENAME,
         TRIM(b.ColumnName) AS ColumnName

      FROM dbc.Tables a
      INNER JOIN dbc.COLUMNS AS b
      ON a.DatabaseName=b.DatabaseName AND a.TABLENAME = b.TABLENAME

      WHERE a.DatabaseName = :DBNAME
      AND a.TABLENAME = :TABLENAME
            AND TableKind = 'T'


DO 
SET SqlTxt =  'SELECT ' || '''' || TRIM(cur.ColumnName) || '''' ||  ', CASE
                           WHEN SUM(CNT) IS NULL THEN 0
                           ELSE SUM(CNT)
                           END AS CntNull

FROM (
SELECT  0 AS cnt    
FROM    ' || TRIM(cur.DBNAME) || '.'  || TRIM(cur.TABLENAME)  ||' )a ;';

CALL dbc.sysexecsql(:SqlTxt);

   END FOR;

END;
```

But when I call the statement I get this error:
CALL Failed.  [5568] SUM_COL:SQL statement is not supported within a stored procedure.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation:
This error occurs when in one of the following situations: a. An unsupported SQL statement is specified in a stored procedure using the dynamic SQL feature of stored procedures. For instance, DATABASE statement, SET SQL statements, multi statement requests, CREATE USER/DATABASE statement without FROM clause, SELECT - INTO SQL or CALL SQL. This is a run-time error.

Looks like you have other syntax errors.  Declare your cursor, open your cursor, etc..  I think you can solve your goal in an easier way, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The SQL statement returns a columnname and 0 as a default value, the sum is because otherwise I would get as many 0 as there are rows in that column and the case is to avoid that I don't get anything when there are no rows. Any ideas on how to fix it?I think that the problem is in the procedure code rather than the statement

Comment: what is the goal of your stored procedure?  you are passing in a database/tablename and what is the output supposed to be/provide you?

Comment: The goal is to get a resultset structures as "columnName", 0. So the procedure should read the string as if it was a query. This should be achieved by reiterating that string for all columnnames available given a certain dbname and table name. But I think that I made poorly the reiteration part.